Error when trying to SCP from Linux remote to Windows 11
I am currently trying to use scp to transfer files from a Linux-based remote server to my local machine from within a Windows Powershell terminal. My machine is installed with Windows 11, though I have previously been working on a machine running Windows 10.
Suppose that I would like to download a set of files with different extensions, e.g. .ext1 and _ext2. When I run the following command in my working directory
scp user@remote:/nobackup/user/example_path/'{*.ext1,*_ext2}' .

I get the error
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\scp.exe: /nobackup/user/example_path/{*.ext1,*_ext2}: No such file or directory

This has me a little confused, given that the above command was working on my old Windows 10 machine. Note that there is no apparent error in the authentication for the remote, and I have tested that the wildcard * formatting is being handled correctly by the remote. From what I can tell, the error results from Windows not being able to handle the brace expansion correctly. I have tried various other methods of trying to escape the braces, e.g., using ", \ or `, but none of these have worked.
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I have trawled through numerous stack overflow posts trying to find the correct solution, and nothing I have thus-far found has worked. Note that I want to avoid running multiple scp commands as the remote server requires a lengthy authentication for each call.

As you correctly point out, the pattern {*.ext1,*_ext2} is clearly not being recognized. In fact, bash-like expressions such as {*.x} are not recognized by scp on my Linux system. Not sure what tool you were using before, but that must have been an extension. Use scp user@remote:/.../'*.ext1' plus user@remote:/.../'*.ext2' and you will be fine.

I think the remote was running bash, so that would be why it was working before.
The reason I wanted to avoid multiple scp commands is because the remote requires authentication for each scp command, which would require 10+ authenatications for what I am trying to do. I will update the question statement to reflect this.
I am mostly confused as to why it no-longer works, more than anything.

As you correctly point out, the pattern {*.ext1,*_ext2} is clearly not being recognized. Not sure what you were using before, but Bash-like expressions such as {*.x} are not recognized by scp on my Linux system, even when the remote has bash available.
A few solutions:

Use multiple commands:
scp user@remote:/example/path/'*.ext1' .
scp user@remote:/example/path/'*.ext2' .


Specify all remote paths in one command:
scp user@remote:/example/path/'*.ext1' user@remote:/example/path/'*.ext2' .


If you are using a bash (or similar) shell, make bash perform the expansion of the arguments for you:
scp user@remote:/example/path/{'*.ext1','*.ext2'} .

This is identical to solution 2 above, but Bash does the expansion for you (notice that the quotes are only inside, so that {...} is expanded by Bash).

You may be able to do the same as solution 3 in PowerShell with a different syntax. I am not sure, not familiar enough with PS. Check out this other post that may help: Powershell equivalent of Bash Brace Expansion for generating lists/arrays.


As pointed out in the comments, commands such as scp user@machine:xxx user@machine:yyy perform multiple SSH connections. You could be able to avoid this by configuring SSH session sharing in your ~/.ssh/config file. On Windows it should be C:\Users\<user>\.ssh\config (or %userprofile%\ssh\config with CMD, or ~/.ssh/config with PowerShell).
See How to reuse an ssh connection (SO) and How to maintain ssh connection for multiple scp transfers? (ServerFault) for more info about this.

These are all great solutions for transferring from servers that do not require very involved authentications, thank you. :) Unfortunately, the use-case that I am targetting would require me to undergo three separate authentication steps per scp command (or file, if using solutions 2 or 3), and so I cannot feasibly use them there.

@PhysyCola I am not sure I follow your logic here. Solution 2 and 3 are a single scp command. It will require only one authentication for all the files.

Unfortunately that does not appear to be the way that they are executed on the remote; it seems to require authentication for each call of user@remote: .

@PhysyCola ohh my bad, you are probably right those are treated as two separate connections... dang it.

@PhysyCola check out the last paragraph I just added, it may help you out.
